# rectify the code.Also need to put user input validation check

Tags: validation, input

Problem Specification: 
Write a C# program using only one class containing the Main() method and a number of other methods within that class to calculate the take-home pay for a commissioned sales employee.
Employee receives 7% of the total sales for a week as commission. This is the gross pay.
The following deductions are made from the gross pay received based on the following:
•   Federal tax rate at 16%. 
•   Retirement contributions is 13%. 
•   Social security tax at 8%.
As part of your solution:
•   Write one method to display appropriate instructions to the user.
•   Write only one method to be invoked or called twice to get the employee name and the total sales for the week separately.
•   Write six separate methods to calculate the following:
o   Total gross pay
o   Federal tax deduction
o   Retirement contribution deduction
o   Social security deduction
o   Total deductions for the week
o   Take home pay for the week
•   Write one method to display the results using appropriate messages , including
o   The employee name,
o   The total sales 
o   The gross pay
o   Federal tax deducted,
o   Social security tax deducted,
o   Retirement contribution,
o   Total deductions
o   Total take home pay

Note:
When calling each of the methods, pass the arguments as variables only.

Program Input
Allow the user to enter the name of the employee and the total sales amount for the week for that employee. Your program is required to handle only one employee.
Note:
The program must generate an appropriate error message if input does not follow the required syntax.
Program output:
Your final output should display all the calculated values, all the defined constants and the name of the employee.
Note:
1.  The output must be displayed in a readable format. 
2.  Test your code using appropriate input

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;   

namespace totalSalaryCalculator
{
    class totalsalarycalculator
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string employeeName;
            double saleForWeek;
            double grossPay;
            double fedTaxDeduction;
            double socialSecDeduction;
            double totalDeductions;
            double takeHomePay;
            double retirementContri;

            DisplayInstructions();
            employeeName = GetInformation();
            saleForWeek = GetInformation();
            grossPay = GetGrossPay(saleForWeek);
            retirementContri = GetRetContri(grossPay);
            socialSecDeduction = GetSSdeduction(grossPay);
            fedTaxDeduction = GetFedTax(grossPay);
            totalDeductions = GetDeduction(fedTaxDeduction, retirementContri, socialSecDeduction);
            takeHomePay = GetNetPay(grossPay, totalDeductions);
            DisplayResults(employeeName, saleForWeek, grossPay, fedTaxDeduction, socialSecDeduction, retirementContri, takeHomePay);
        }

        public static void DisplayInstructions()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This Program Calculates the Net Salary" + " of the employee for a week\n");
            Console.WriteLine("How much of the sale's target you were able to achieve for one week\n");
            Console.WriteLine("you will be asked to enter the total sales for a week\n");
            Console.WriteLine("The gross pay will be calculated accordingly\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Gross pay is seven pecent" + " of the Total sales for a week\n");
            Console.WriteLine();               
            Console.WriteLine("The Retirement Contribution will also be deducted from the Gross pay\n");
            Console.WriteLine("The taxes deducted will be Federal Tax,Social Security Tax\n");
            Console.WriteLine("The Federal tax will be 16 percent of the gross pay\n");
            Console.WriteLine("The Social Security Tax will be 8 percent of the Gross pay\n");
            Console.WriteLine("The Retirement Contribution Will be 13 percent of the Gross pay\n");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("\nYou will be asked to enter your name");
            Console.WriteLine("\nAnd You will be asked to enter the total sale you were able to achieve for a week");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key when you are ready to begin");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
        }
        public static double GetInformation(string name,string sale)
        {
            string inputvalue;
            string inputvalue2;
            double totalSales;
            double nameOfPerson;
            Console.Write("Enter the name of Employee: ");
            inputvalue= Console.ReadLine();
            nameOfPerson = double.Parse(inputvalue);
            Console.Write("Enter the Total Sales for the Week: ");
            inputvalue2 = Console.ReadLine();
            totalSales = double.Parse(inputvalue2);
            return ( nameOfPerson + totalSales);


        }


        public static double GetGrossPay(double saleForWeek)
        {
            double grosspay;
            grosspay = 7 / 100 * saleForWeek;
            return grosspay;
        }
        public static double GetFedTax(double grossPay)
        {
            double fedtax;
            fedtax = 16 / 100 * grossPay;
            return fedtax;
        }
        public static double GetRetContri(double grossPay)
        {
            double retcontri;
            retcontri = 13 / 100 * grossPay;
            return retcontri;
        }
        public static double GetSSdeduction(double grossPay)
        {
            double ssdeduction;
            ssdeduction = 8 / 100 * grossPay;
            return ssdeduction;
        }
        public static double GetDeduction(double fedTaxDeduction, double retirementContri, double socialSecDeduction)
        {
            double totdeductions;
            totdeductions = fedTaxDeduction + retirementContri + socialSecDeduction;
            return totdeductions;
        }
        public static double GetNetPay(double grossPay, double totalDeductions)
        {
            double netpay;
            netpay = grossPay - totalDeductions;
            return netpay;
        }
        public static void DisplayResults(string employeeName, double saleForWeek, double grossPay, double fedTaxDeduction, double retirementContri, double socialSecDeduction,
            double takeHomePay)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Employee Name: " + employeeName);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Sales entered by the Employee: "+ saleForWeek);
            Console.WriteLine("Gross Pay for a week: " + grossPay);
            Console.WriteLine("Federal Tax Deduction for a week: " + fedTaxDeduction);
            Console.WriteLine("Social security Deduction for a week: " + socialSecDeduction);
            Console.WriteLine("Retirement Contribution for a week:  " + retirementContri);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Deductions for a week: " + GetDeduction(fedTaxDeduction, retirementContri, socialSecDeduction));
            Console.WriteLine("Take Home Pay for a week:   " + takeHomePay);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because seems like a homework.